# Turan graph maximizes the minimal vertex degree

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that for every graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $tr(n)$ edges, the following inequality holds: 
>   $$\delta(G) \le \delta(T_r(n))$$
>   where $T_r(n)$ stands for Turan's graph and $tr(n)$ for its number of edges.
>
> Hint: compare sum of degrees in each graph.

Below I show my solution, hope that someone will check it and help with the second part:

Let's assume for contradiction that $\delta(G) > \delta(T_r(n))$. If $d:=\delta(T_r(n))$, then every vertex in $T_r(n)$ has a degree of $d$ or $d+1$, but at least one of degree $d$; whereas in $G$ every vertex has a degree of at least $d+1$. This implies that $\sum_{x \in V(G)} d_G(x)>\sum_{x \in V(T_r(n))} d_{T_r(n)}(x)$. From the handshake lemma, this would mean that the number of edges in $G$ is greater than number of edges in $T_r(n)$, contradiction.

Now the second part is to prove that $\Delta(G) \ge \Delta(T_r(n))$ for the same $G$ as earlier. Unfortunately, this trick does not work...

Comment: What have you tried so far? People are often more willing to help if you have shown some effort and explain what your thought process is.

Comment: Yes, as said above, at least show what your thoughts are on the matter

Comment: Below I show my solution, hope that someone will check it and help with the second part. I don't really know what's wrong with the question, I put all the information I had at the moment and it's assessed as not useful and clear

Comment: Hi @katta. You post was closed because it didn't show any effort on your part. It strongly reads just like a homework question that you didn't want to do so you posted here for someone to do for you. Your presented solution shows that this is not the case, though. For future reference you should include some evidence of effort in your posts. Had your original question included the answer you posted below and had instead focused on asking how to show that $\Delta(G) \ge \Delta(T_r(n))$, it would have been very well received on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved :) let's assume for contradiction that $\delta(G) > \delta(T_r(n))$. If $d:=\delta(T_r(n))$, then every vertex in $T_r(n)$ has a degree of $d$ or $d+1$, but at least one of degree $d$; whereas in $G$ every vertex has a degree of at least $d+1$. This implies that $\sum_{x \in V(G)} d_G(x)>\sum_{x \in V(T_r(n))} d_{T_r(n)}(x)$. From the handshake lemma, this would mean that the number of edges in $G$ is greater than number of edges in $T_r(n)$, contradiction.

Now the second part is to prove that $\Delta(G) \ge \Delta(T_r(n))$ for the same $G$ as earlier. Unfortunately, this trick does not work...